# I do not receive any response from flathub

Tags: networking, internet, application, flatpak

When I run `sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`, I do not get any responses, and command does not finish. I can open flathub.org in the browser, and also I have its ping in the terminal:

```
PING flathub.org (8.43.85.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from flathub.org (8.43.85.5): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=289 ms
64 bytes from flathub.org (8.43.85.5): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=313 ms
64 bytes from flathub.org (8.43.85.5): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=235 ms

--- flathub.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 234.656/279.186/313.462/32.979 ms
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `--if-not-exists` means "do nothing if the provided remote already exists".

Comment: Command does not finish. It tries much time, but can't add the repo. If the repo exits, the command would finish.